# Could not load System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms error when calling CSharpCompilation.Emit

Tags: c#, roslyn, .net-standard

I'm trying to create an in memory assembly using the `CSharpCompilation.Emit` method but for some odd reason it's always throwing an exception saying that it can't load `System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms`. The project it runs in is .netstandard, but the startup project is .net framework, not sure if that matters.

Here is the code:

```
  var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
            var assemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
            var netstandardAssembly =
                assemblies.First(x => !x.IsDynamic && x.Location.Contains("netstandard"));   

            MetadataReference[] references = {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(netstandardAssembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.dll")),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Core.dll")),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "Microsoft.CSharp.dll")),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "mscorlib.dll")),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Data.dll")),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, "System.Runtime.dll")),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location)
            };

   CSharpCompilation compilation =
                CSharpCompilation.Create(name)
                    .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
                    .WithReferences(references)
                    .AddSyntaxTrees(CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"namespace Example.Main
{
    public class Class1
    {
        
    }
}"));

            try
            {
                byte[] assemblyBytes;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var result = compilation.Emit(ms);
                    if (!result.Success)
                    {
                        IEnumerable<Diagnostic> failures = result.Diagnostics.Where(diagnostic =>
                            diagnostic.IsWarningAsError ||
                            diagnostic.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);

                        foreach (Diagnostic diagnostic in failures)
                        {
                            _logger.LogDebug($"{diagnostic.Id}: {diagnostic.GetMessage()}");
                        }
                    }

                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    assemblyBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }

                return assemblyBytes;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Could not compile");
                return null;
            }
```

Here is the stack trace:

````
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.EmitOptions.ValidateOptions(DiagnosticBag diagnostics, CommonMessageProvider messageProvider, Boolean isDeterministic)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.CheckOptionsAndCreateModuleBuilder(DiagnosticBag diagnostics, IEnumerable`1 manifestResources, EmitOptions options, IMethodSymbol debugEntryPoint, Stream sourceLinkStream, IEnumerable`1 embeddedTexts, CompilationTestData testData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.Emit(Stream peStream, Stream metadataPEStream, Stream pdbStream, Stream xmlDocumentationStream, Stream win32Resources, IEnumerable`1 manifestResources, EmitOptions options, IMethodSymbol debugEntryPoint, Stream sourceLinkStream, IEnumerable`1 embeddedTexts, CompilationTestData testData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.Emit(Stream peStream, Stream pdbStream, Stream xmlDocumentationStream, Stream win32Resources, IEnumerable`1 manifestResources, EmitOptions options, IMethodSymbol debugEntryPoint, Stream sourceLinkStream, IEnumerable`1 embeddedTexts, Stream metadataPEStream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)```
````